# How to control website tinting in Safari 15

Tags: html, css, safari

In Safari 15, a new feature got released which tints the address bar and tab bar to match the color of the header of the current website.

I've noticed that this new feature does not work on any of the websites I previously created. Which makes me wonder. How exactly does this website tinting feature work? Can we control which color the bar will get using `CSS` or a combination of `HTML` and `CSS`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After looking around online a bit, I found that you can use the following `<meta>` tags in your HTML, so set the color of the address bar:

```html
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#ffffff">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#ffffff">
```

[Source](https://www.geekinsta.com/how-to-change-the-color-of-address-bar-to-match-the-color-of-your-site/)

So to get the color in Safari, the `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` will likely work.

(I do not have Safari, so I cannot test this myself. I think this would work though)

Comment: That indeed works! Seems like the `theme-color` meta tag also includes Safari on MacOs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you would like a separate color for dark mode, use `<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">`. Note sure if it works for `msapplication-navbutton-color` and `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style`.

Answer (score 2):

You can learn how to do this at https://developer.apple.com/safari/.

Some colors are prohibited; they won’t work. [Learn More](https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/#prohibited-colors)